# Update 2000 records with one query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a Database table:

`Item`

`ID (uniqueidentifier)`

`Index (int)`

I have a list of 2000 key-value pairs items where the key is `ID` and value is `Index`, which i need to update it. How can i update all the 2000 items from database using one single sql query?

Right now i have something like this:

```
// this dictionary has 2000 values
Dictionary<Guid, int> values = new Dictionary<Guid,int>(); 
foreach(KeyValuePair<Guid, int> item in values)
{
    _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE [Item] SET [Index] = @p0 WHERE [Id] = @p1", item.Value, item.Key);
}
```

However, i am making too many requests to the SQL Server, and i want to improve this.

Comment: if you are wanting to stick closer to using EF with linq rather than raw SQL, I would have a look at https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [table value parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send those values to SQL Server and update `Items` table in one shot:

```
CREATE TYPE KeyValueType AS TABLE 
(
    [Key] GUID,
    [Value] INT
);

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_UpdateItems
@pairs KeyValueType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE I
    SET [Index] = P.Value
    FROM
        [Item] I
        INNER JOIN @pairs P ON P.Id = I.Id
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to update in that manner and have no other alternative - the main way around it could be this rather "ugly" technique (and therefore rarely used, but still works pretty well);

Make all 2000 statements in one string, and execute that one string. That makes one call to the database with the 2000 updates in it.

So basically something like this (code not made to actually run, it's an example so t

```
Dictionary<Guid, int> values = new Dictionary<Guid, int>();
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, int> item in values)
{
    sb.Append(String.Format("UPDATE [Item] SET [Index] = {0} WHERE [Id] = '{1}';", item.Value, item.Key));

}
_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sb.ToString);
```